# feature branch diverging from origin/feature

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I have a master branch and a feature branch.
I have few comitts on my feature branch which my team mates have pushed to.
There are few commits on master too.

I want the latest changes on both branches and want to have feature branch sync with
master branch.

So, I have performed the below steps.

on master:

```
> git checkout master
> git pull
> git pull --rebase
```

on feature branch:

```
> git checkout feature
> git pull
> git pull --rebase
> git rebase origin/master
> git status
```

git status gives me an output saying
*Your branch and 'origin/feature' have diverged,
and have 97 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)*

When I use *git pull*, it ends up giving me lots of merge conflicts.

How do I resolve this? Please help.

Comment: inspect the output of `git log --graph --oneline feature origin/feature`, try to figure out why `origin/feature` has 4 commits which aren't on your own branch

Comment: Running `git pull` AND `git pull --rebase` is certainly a mistake. Use either or, but not both.